# Salesforce DX error

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am following the trailhead provided by Salesforce for Salesforce DX and when I run the command "sfdx" I see the below error message. I have set the path variable for GIT correctly but not sure why this error is coming up.

Error message:

C:\Program Files\sfdx>sfdx
panic: Get https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-cli/channels/stable/windows-x64: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x00\x00\x00\x02\x02("

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x6632a0, 0xc042008bd0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1af
main.must(0x7b92c0, 0xc042008bd0)
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/io.go:115 +0x63
main.GetUpdateManifest(0x6a4875, 0x7, 0x6a3c0d, 0x3, 0x7b92c0)
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/install.go:104 +0x272
main.GetUpdateManifest(0x6a4875, 0x7, 0x6a3c0d, 0x3, 0x0)
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/install.go:102 +0x2f4
main.Install()
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/install.go:33 +0x100
main.main()
        /home/ubuntu/.go_workspace/src/github.com/heroku/cli/main.go:18 +0x3a

Comment: I have installed the salesforce DX plugin too.

Comment: By any chance did you install heroku cli or sfdx pilot version ealier?

Comment: I did install Heroku cli earlier @manishg

Comment: Things to try: upgrading sfdx, configure a proxy if necessary (http://sforce.co/2hLmyDQ), set debug environment variables (HEROKU_DEBUG=true SFDX_DEBUG=true)